# C#/Tamir.SharpSsh: System.IO.IOException: Pipe closed

Tags: c#, ssh

I'm using `Tamir.SharpSsh` to upload a file to a ssh server with the code below but I'm getting `System.IO.IOException: Pipe closed.` Any clue why?

```
SshTransferProtocolBase scp = new Scp(SSH_HOST, SSH_USER);
scp.Password = SSH_PASSWORD;
scp.Connect();
foreach (string file in files)
{
    string remotePath = "incoming/" + new FileInfo(file).Name;
    scp.Put(file, remotePath);
}
scp.Close();
```

Regards
/Niels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For future references: Apparently the server only accepted Sftp connections. So I changed to:

```
SshTransferProtocolBase scp = new Sftp(SSH_HOST, SSH_USER);
```

Answer (score 4):

I had exactly the same problem ("Pipe Closed") when trying to transfer files.
Changing to

```
Sftp scp = new Sftp(SSH_HOST, SSH_USER);
```

solved the problem.
Thanks
Stefano

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might have to do with permissions on the remote server.